# is There a Column Count Property in VB.net like MS Access?

Tags: vb.net

I am working with vb.net and DataBase

Let us say I have two related tables:

- Employee(EmpID, EmpName, DepID  as ForeignKey)
- Department(DepID,DepName)

And I want to show the table Employee in a Datagrid, but I need to show the department name instead of the department ID, as can be done in MS Access So easly By setting Column Count to 2, and Column Width to 0;1
Since it is annoying and sometimes  we cannot memorize what does the ID refers to.

How Can it Be Done?

Thanks for advance :)

Comment: is this a webform or winforms?  the DataGrid is a webforms control

Comment: users shouldnt have to know or even see IDs, just use a JOIN to resolve the DepID into the name and show that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to write a an sql query in your datasource this way:

```
select EmpID, EmpName, Employee.DepID ,DepName
from Employee inner join Department 
on Employee.DepID=Employee.DepID
```

in your Datagrid replace DepID with DepName in source view.

Comment: Thanks Okonkwo, :)   Thats the right way to do it :$

Comment: Glad it worked. Thank you for marking my answer. Just voted the question up